# Changing the size of an element in jQuery while maintaining relative size changes in CSS

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I have an element which is a circle that grows when hovered over and shrinks slightly when clicked on. This is accomplished using the `:hover` and `:active` CSS pseudo-classes:

```
#circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
#circle:hover {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}
#circle:active {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
}
```

If I use the following jQuery to increase the size of the circle, then the circle remains that size even when hovered over or clicked on (understandably).

```
var circle = $("#circle");
circle.width(200);
circle.height(200);
```

[JSFiddle available here](https://jsfiddle.net/1g09700k/2/).

How can I increase the size of the circle in jQuery but still have it grow when hovered over and shrink slightly when clicked on? E.g. when I set the size to 200px, it will grow to 240px when hovered over and 220px when clicked on.

**Note:** The 100px and 200px etc. values are just examples. I am looking for a solution that will allow me to change the size of the circle to any size and still maintain the growing/shrinking on hover/click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a CSS solution for this: put the circle in a container `div` so that that the `width` and `height` in the CSS can be relative to the size of the container and then change the size of the container instead of the circle. This requires using `transform` to keep the circle centred but seems to work well.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="circle"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
#circle {
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#circle:hover {
    width: 120%;
    height: 120%;
    transform: translate(-10%, -10%);
}
#circle:active {
    width: 110%;
    height: 110%;
    transform: translate(-5%, -5%);
}
```

Example changing the size of the circle:

```
var circle = $("#circle");
var container = $("#container");
circle.click(function() {
    container.width(200);
    container.height(200);
});
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/1g09700k/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery **.mouseover()** and **.mouseleave()** events.
you can see the updated [jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/1g09700k/1/)

```
var circle = $("#circle");
circle.css('border-radius', '50%');
circle.mouseover(function(){
    circle.css('width', '200px');
  circle.css('height', '200px');
});

circle.mouseleave(function(){
    circle.css('width', '100px');
  circle.css('height', '100px');
});
```

**Edit:**

```
var circle = $("#circle");
var width = circle.width();
circle.mouseover(function(){
  circle.css('width', width*1.2);
  circle.css('height', width*1.2);
});

circle.mouseleave(function(){
  circle.css('width', width);
  circle.css('height', width);
});

circle.click(function(){
  circle.css('width', width*1.1);
  circle.css('height',width*1.1);
});
```

Comment: That's not quite what I'm trying to do. Once I've clicked the circle I want it to be 200px in size, 240px when hovered over, and 220px when clicked. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: and when the mouse leave the circle what size you need the circle to be. Sorry for my english

Comment: Whatever size the circle was before. If the circle was 100px, it will need to be 100px when the mouse leaves, if the circle was 200px, it will need to be 200px when the mouse leaves. I don't think your solution is going to solve this problem.

Comment: No, that's still not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for something that can dynamically make the circle grow/shrink on hover/click even when the circle has its size changed dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, set the border radius for your circle to 50% at all times like so:

```
#circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

**Then**, remove your #circle:hover and #circle:active CSS statements.

**Finally**, replace your current jQuery code with this one:

```
var circle = $("#circle");

circle.click(function() {
    circle.width(200);
    circle.height(200);
});

circle.mouseover(function() {
    circle.animate({
        height: "+=20",
        width: "+=20"
    }, 250);
});

circle.mouseleave(function() {
    circle.animate({
        height: "-=20",
        width: "-=20"
    }, 250);
});

circle.mousedown(function() {
    circle.animate({
       height: '-=10',
       width: "-=10"
    }, 250);
});
```

The change in size currently takes 250 milliseconds, but you can adjust that easily by just changing the values at the end of the animate() functions.

Comment: Can I use percentages instead of hardcoded values? What about the equivalent of `:active`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot completely about the :active. Edited the jQuery, it now has the :active effect from the mousedown() function. I am not 100% sure if you can use percentage values with this concept, I tried changing the += and -= to *= but it didn't work. I'm sure there's a way to use percentages though.

Comment: The relative size thing is really what I'm looking for. It also needs the `mouseup` function to fully mimic `:active`. But event then the animation isn't the same: if you click on the circle a bunch of times the animation will keep going after you've stopped clicking. Also, adding both `mouseup` and `mousedown` seems to stop the `click` event working.